# How to fill a form with mongo database data with aps.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb

Here is my issue, i have a form that i fill and this information are stored inside my database. What i want now is to make a button that load this information and fill the form with it !

But i can't find how to achieve this easily. Any clue about it ?

I've tried something like this :

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   GViewModel model = new GViewModel();
   return View(model);
}

public ActionResult LCalabria(string designation)
{
   GViewModel model = new GViewModel();
   return View("CGalabria", model);
}
```

And in my view :

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Load", "Gar")" id="" class="btn">LOAD</a>
```

So i know it won't work, well it'll do what i ask but without filling the form ! How can i do in my LCalabria to tell retrieve information form base ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there id an article written by Shayne about how to configure and use MangoDB with EF in MVC

http://tattoocoder.com/building-vnext-web-api-using-mvc-6-mongodb-azure/

you need to Google :-)

Comment: Thanks ! I'm googling but hard to find something explained good, i'll read this :)